# CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.Controls.get'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I know there have been a lot of questions regarding this subject but none seem to help me in my situation so I'm posting another.

I was given a project and asked to split the project out into separate controls.  Originally there was a folder in the project called "events" that referenced a control called "EventsRssFeedControl".  My boss asked me to separate the events and EventsRssFeedControl and put them together in their own project.  So I did that.  I changed all the namespaces and got everything to compile.  But when I try to navigate there, I get an error.
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.Controls.get'

Source Error:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedDate" value="<%= UMNEventsRssFeedControl.Controls.UMNEventsRssFeedControl.SelectedDateStr %>"/>
```

My code looks like this and I'm confused by calling it "non-static" and more confused as to why it doesn't work.

```
        private static string _selectedDateStr;
    public static string SelectedDateStr
    {
        get { return _selectedDateStr; }
        set { _selectedDateStr = value; }
    }
```

It works in the old project and the only things changed were the namespaces and the calls to the new namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your namespace and class are named the same thing. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks Pubb!  I know, I know!  (hanging head in shame)

Comment: Turns out that was my problem.  Having a namespace named the same as the control confused me and it.  I renamed the namespace and tweaked the calls to the control a bit and it worked.  I will hang my head in shame again for being silly about namespace names.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually not at `SelectedDateStr`.

`UMNEventsRssFeedControl.Controls` is asking for static getter of the property `Controls` of `UMNEventsRssFeedControl`. Obviously, `Controls` is an instance property of the mentioned class.

You need to supply an instance of `UMNEventsRssFeedControl` for the code to work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Vlad.  I'm a bit new to this sort of thing so it does confuse me a bit.  What I don't understand is that this works when it's part of the larger project but not when it's split out.  Yet, I think I grabbed every reference to this control so if the code created an instance, then I should have that as well.  Could you give me an example of how I would go about creating an instance of UMNEventsRssFeedControl?

Comment: @invisible: Well, in a bigger project there is perhaps a _field_ or _property_ of some class named `UMNEventsRssFeedControl` (and of type `UMNEventsRssFeedControl` as well), so the code interprets `UMNEventsRssFeedControl` as an instance reference and not a type.